# Common game controls/ User interface libraries or source code?

Tags: c++, user-interface, user-controls, interface-builder

Sorry for the ackward title, but i don't know what to call it exactly. **I'm looking for code or libraries that allow easy creation of commonly used user input devices, and code/libs that make gaming controls easy to set up (i'm using SFML and Box2D at the moment)**

I don't want to re-invent things like buttons, arrows being placed wherever the mouse is located, and more game specific items such as "controls settings" or even being able to drag objects around with the mouse.

More **specifically i want source code for interfaces that....**

- Makes Buttons and Textboxes easy to create
- allows mouse input to press buttons or drag objects in games
- has "Focuses" (like a textbox being able to gain focus and be typed in)
- Is compatable with SFML/Box2D

**and code for common game mechanics/controls that....**

- Allows easy setup of controls for a game
- Makes events like clicking and holding on an object easy to setup, as so objects can be dragged around afterward

***Are there any simple libraries or resources out there that i can use to avoid spending much of my time coding these now standard input devices/tecniques?***

Comment: Will you be using SFML inside widgets from another GUI toolkit (GTKmm, Qt, wxWidgets)? If so, there are graphical interface designers written to work with these toolkits (Glade, Qt Designer, and wxGlade, respectively).

Comment: no i'm currently just learning all this stuff and completely independent from any GUI toolkit or platform specific toolkits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CEGUI is the type of thing you are looking for:

http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

It is a GUI framework to work with OpenGL. Some others can be found in [this list](http://www.sfml-dev.org/wiki/en/projects/gui).

---

Still, if I were you, I would just use a major toolkit, such as GTK, Qt, or wxWidgets combined with SFML instead of dealing with CEGUI.

SFML has guides for Qt and wxWidgets with the rest of them at http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/.

I have created my own little guide for GTK here: http://lalaland.github.com/gtkGuide.html